# Did Schwab's Emerging Market ETF really pay no foreign tax related to the final distribution in 2018?

Tags: united-states, taxes, etf, dividends, tax-credit

According to the 1099 from my broker, the Schwab Emerging Market ETF (SCHE) did not pay any foreign taxes associated with its final dividend for 2018, declared 12/28/2018. I'm quite skeptical as Schwab's Developed Market ETF (SCHF) also had a dividend around then but did report foreign taxes paid. Unfortunately, unlike other ETF providers, I can't find any official information on the Schwab Funds website.

Is there some direct source which confirms whether or not this is the case? Alternatively, if you held this stock and have a different broker from me, does your broker's 1099 also say there was no foreign tax paid? (I use Merrill.)

Answer (score 1):

I have SCHE and SCHF at Schwab directly.  I see around $0.0754/share foreign tax for SCHE.  I also have SCHF at Merrill and they did not report the approx $0.0872/share foreign tax - this is still unresolved with them as of March 10th.  Outside of my 1099 from Schwab, I have not found anywhere where they report this information (unlike BlackRock iShares for example).